# How do I hide a certain tab from the tabnavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to hide the "Summary" tab from the tab bar below, but can't quite figure out how I can do this.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({
Overview: {
    screen: Overview
},
Camera: {
    screen: Camera
},
Summary: {
    screen: Summary
}
}, {
tabBarPosition: 'top',
swipeEnabled: true,
tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#f2f2f2',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#2EC4B6',
    inactiveTintColor: '#666',
    labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 22,
        padding: 12
    }
}
});

export default createAppContainer(Tab);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using a custom BottomBar and hiding the tab when the screen appeared:

```
    tabBarComponent: (props) => (<BottomBar {...props} ></BottomBar>) //Navigator Configs
```

The bottombar i have is like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
var { height } = Dimensions.get("window")
const HiddenView = () => <View style={{ display: 'none' }} />
const TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper = ({
    onPress,
    onLongPress,
    testID,
    accessibilityLabel,
    ...props
}) => {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            testID={testID}
            hitSlop={{
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
                top: 5,
                bottom: 5,
            }}
            accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        >
            <View {...props} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
export default TabBarComponent = props => {
    return <BottomTabBar
        {...props}
        style={styles.bottomBarStyle}
        getButtonComponent={({ route }) => {
            if (route.key === "Summary" )
                return HiddenView
            else return TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper
        }}
    />
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bottomBarStyle: {
        height: (height * 10.625) / 100
    }
})
```

Let me know if this creates new issues